# Drawing app performance

Tags: ios, drawing, cgcontext

I have created a drawing app to draw when you touch the screen and it works very smooth in the simulator but when I tested it on my iPad 2 it slows down and it takes very long time to draw I am using these lines of code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];



    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:self.view.frame];

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 7.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0, 1, 0, 1);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());


    [drawImage setFrame:self.view.frame];
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
}
```

I think the problem is with calling drawInRect: method in touchMoved: method

Comment: Try analyzing this with the Time Profiler instrument - It will tell you what method calls are using the most process time. Check out the "Core Animation Essentials" WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/index.php

Comment: This seems like it would be a great app to use displayLink.  Call the setNeedsDisplay only so many times per second no matter how many touch events happen.

Comment: yeah , i know that the error in the drawInRect: call , because when i removed it works smoothly but the drawing is not perfect in this case

Answer (score 1):

1. Build up a UIBezierPath in your touchesMoved and don't do any drawing there.
2. Call setNeedsDisplay in touchesMoved.
3. Override drawRect and draw your path there.

OR

Use set the layer backing for your view to a CAShapeLayer and add the points to the layer in touchesMoved.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer. @user3330895 Don't expect anyone to write the code for you; you'll learn much more by doing it yourself. Stephen's answer is pretty clear -- if you don't understand it, you should a) read up on how you're supposed to draw in a view, and b) ask specifically about what you don't understand.